# Using brentq with two lists of data

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find the root(s) of a line which is defined by data like:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [-2,4,6,8,4]
```

I have started by using interpolation but I have been told I can then use the brentq function. How can I use brentq from two lists? I thought continuous functions are needed for it.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation of brentq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) says, the first argument must be a *continuous* function. Therefore, you must first generate, from your data, a function that will return a value for each parameter passed to it. You can do that with `interp1d`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.optimize import brentq
x, y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([-2,4,6,8,4])
f = interp1d(x,y, kind='linear')  # change kind to something different if you want e.g. smoother interpolation
brentq(f, x.min(), x.max()) # returns: 1.33333
```

You could also use splines to generate the continuous function needed for `brentq`.